# Darken Layer Outline in photoshop

Tags: adobe, photoshop, layer, edges

How can I darken my layer edges in photoshop?
As you can see in image below the layer edge is in a color like light pink or purple. how can I make the edges black?

[Click for Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSkBt.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself!

1.Select the layer
2. Go to Layer -> Layer Style -> Stroke -> Choose the proper size